# create an ES6 class with Array like behaviour

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a class that behaves a bit like an array. There are two things that I would like to have:

- has to be iterable
- should allow for property accessing via `[index]` where `index` is an integer

Making a class iterable is fairly easy:

```
class MyList {
    constructor() {
        this._list = [1, 2, 3];
    }
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this._list.values();
    }
}
```

The above allows an instance of the class to be iterated over:

```
let myList = new MyList();
for (let item of myList) {
    console.log(item); // prints out 1, 2, 3
}
```

Figuring out how to implement the second requirement turns out it's not as easy and the only think I found would be to extend `Array`. But this means that I would have to override most of the methods inherited from `Array` as I would need those methods to do something else than the built in behaviour.

Is there a way to achieve what I am asking? If so, what would be the best approach to do it?

Comment: Is it required that a `var test = MyList(); test[2] = 1;`  results in a `[undefined, undefined, 2]`  with a `test.length` of `3`?  Or is it only important, that the data is accessible by `[]` ?

Comment: @t.niese I guess not, I haven't thought about that :)

Comment: Why do you use `_list`  to store the data, instead of storing it directly with the object: `this[idx] = 2`  instead of `this._list[idx] = 2`. Is there a reason why you don't want to do that?

Comment: @t.niese hmmm, that is actually a good question. It was just an example and it was how I had the implementation before, I stored the values on a private property (I am doing with Typescript, I realize that there are no private properties at this point in JS). But I think it should be fine to store it directly on the class.

Comment: Isn't it possible to just inherit the prototype from the Array object?

Comment: @jonKoops it is, you can just `class MyList extend Array {}`, but that would leave me with a lot of methods that I would have to override tap into and behaviour (that because I have a few of my own methods that are similar to Array's own methods but with slightly different behaviour).

Comment: A small addition in the event that you target a browser or an engine that does not support es 6 natively but if you will use some transpiler: up to es5 inheriting from an Array does not work well or at least will have some unexpected results.

Comment: How are you going to be adding elements? You only illustrate doing it statically in the constructor.

Comment: @Jmm I will be adding elements internally and with the methods that will be exposed on the class eventually.

Comment: So, what else do you want your class to do? Why would you not use a plain Array?

Comment: " But this means that I would have to override most of the methods inherited from `Array` as I would need those methods to do something else than the built in behaviour." -- wouldn't you need to define those methods anyway then?

Comment: @Bergi the class will sync all the values with a push server. So when I add something locally, the push server will be notified and will save the values as well and then notify the other connected clients which have the same kind of class on their and, thus they will sync the new values locally. That is the reason why I need to do a little more when the array changes shape. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Proxy` to intercept assignments.

Comment: @Bergi I haven't looked into how `Proxy` works yet, I'll give it a try and see how it could be of use, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you can store properties under integer-like string keys, e. g. `foo['0'] = 'bar'` and access them with integers, e. g. `foo[0] // => bar`. Assigning with an integer also works. Thanks to @JMM for pointing this stuff out.

Thus, the solution is as simple as:

```
class Foo {
  constructor (...args) {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      this[i] = args[i];
    }
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return Object
      .keys(this)
      .map(key => this[key])
      .values();
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('a', 'b', 'c');

for (let item of foo) {
  console.log(item); // prints out a, b, c
}

console.log(foo[1]); // prints out b
```

[Demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=false&code=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor%20(...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20args.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20args%5Bi%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this).map(key%20%3D%3E%20this%5Bkey%5D).values()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo('a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c')%3B%0A%0Afor%20(let%20item%20of%20foo)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(item)%3B%20%2F%2F%20prints%20out%20a%2C%20b%2C%20c%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(foo%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20prints%20out%20b).

Comment: It should just be `foo[0] = 'bar'`. This general approach would work as long as they're kept in sync. As long as when an element is added / deleted / modified in the internal array the change is reflected to the `this[n]` props.

Comment: "It should just be `foo[0] = 'bar'`" -- isn't it what I'm doing in the code?

Comment: I'm talking about the part I quoted directly from your answer: "`foo['0'] = 'bar'`"

Comment: It's not a syntax or runtime error, just something that it doesn't make sense to do or encourage. You could equally senselessly write `foo[(0)]`, for example.